# Sending FormData from modal to parent component's method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem calling parent method - HandleInsert(formData) with the "formData" argument being made on the child component.

**On the parent component (relevant code)**

```
addModalClose = () => {
        this.setState( {
            addModalShow : false
        });
    }

    addModalOpen = () => {
        this.setState( {
            addModalShow : true
        });
}

async HandleDelete(id : string) {
        this.setState({
            tickets: await api.deleteTickets(id)
        })
    }


and I update props of Modal here:

<Button id="button" className="add_ticket" onClick={this.addModalOpen}>New Ticket</Button>
                        {/*define new props for Modal component in parent component*/}
                        <AddModal
                            show={this.state.addModalShow}
                            onHide={this.addModalClose}
                            onSubmit={this.HandleInsert}
                        />
```

**On the child component: (the modal itself)**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Modal, Button, Row, Col, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {App} from './App'

export class AddModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email : "",
            title : "",
            content : ""
        }
    }


    onHide;
    onSubmit;

    handleEmailChange = e => {
        this.setState({email: e.target.value});
    };
    handleTitleChange = e  => {
        this.setState({title: e.target.value});
    };
    handleContentChange = e => {
        this.setState({content: e.target.value});
    };



    render(){
        let formData = new FormData();
        return(
            <Modal
                {...this.props}
                size="lg"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                centered
            >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                        Ticket Details:
                    </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1" >
                            <Form.Label>Email:</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="name@example.com" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmailChange}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput2">
                            <Form.Label>Title:</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleChange}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
                            <Form.Label>Content:</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control as="textarea" rows="3" value={this.state.content} onChange={this.handleContentChange}/>
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>

                { formData.append("id", "bded4175-a519-5dee-abed-014e7242e6f0")}
                { formData.append("title", this.state.title)}
                { formData.append("content", this.state.content)}
                { formData.append("userEmail",this.state.email)}
                { formData.append("creationTime", new Date())}

<Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="success" onClick={() => this.props.onSubmit(formData)}>Create</Button>
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

the error I'm getting is this:
where it wont understand that it's a function.. 
how I define parent/child relationship? it's not enough just calling component from one compoenent to another?

I'm new on react so I don't get quite well those notions.

[image]

Comment: I dont see the form data being created on the parent, but on the child? What do you expect to happen when the 'create' button is clicked? The data should be passed to the parent? Then make a method for this in the parent and say `onCreate={this.MyParentMethod}` and in child `onClick={this.props.MyParentMethod(formData)}`

Comment: Thanks man, I've updated the post and now I get this problem.

Comment: My bad, probably should be `onClick={() => this.props.HandleInsert(formData)}>Create</Button>`

Answer (score 1):

you are doing this wrong

```
onCreate(formData)={this.HandleInsert(formData)}
```

this is should be assing like

```
    onCreate={(formData)=>{this.HandleInsert(formData)}}
```

updated answer

1.where is HandleInsert is defined in parent component???

```
<Button id="button" className="add_ticket" onClick={this.addModalOpen}>New 
 Ticket</Button>
            <AddModal
            show={this.state.addModalShow}
            onHide={this.addModalClose}
            onSubmit={this.HandleInsert}
            />
```

2.your child component is may not receiving HandleInsert from parent component as props.
3.as i can see in current code

```
 <Modal.Footer>
     <Button variant="success" onClick={this.props.HandleInsert(formData)}>Create</Button>
     <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
 </Modal.Footer>
```

you are calling handleInsert again in wrong way it should be like

```
 onClick={()=>{this.props.HandleInser(formData)}}
```

another thing is where  FormData is defined or imported in your code??

Comment: how does it know what is formData? it's on the other component.. no?

Comment: @lolttr11 i have updated my answer please check it.sorry for late reply!

Comment: Thanks, from a blog I've read they say somthing a bit different, what do you think about this option? (I'm updating the post now), I can't run it at the moment because I have npm issues..